# MySQL returning two different results from query vs stored procedure

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-8.0

I'm baffled as to why MySQL Workbench returns 7 (the correct answer) for this query

```
SELECT ScheduleLocationEventColorID 
FROM schedulelocationeventcolor 
WHERE ScheduleID = 1 AND LocationID = 1;
```

but returns 1 (incorrect) for the equivalent in a stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `test`(
    IN locationID INT,
    IN scheduleID INT
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE slecID INT;

    SELECT ScheduleLocationEventColorID 
    INTO slecID 
    FROM schedulelocationeventcolor 
    WHERE ScheduleID = scheduleID AND LocationID = locationID
    LIMIT 1;
    
    SELECT slecID;
END

-- calling the stored procedure here: 
CALL `test`(1, 1);
```

I tried changing the inputs in the stored procedure call, but I cannot figure out for the life of me why I keep getting a 1 when the result should be a 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should name your procedure parameters something different from your column names. [Column names are case-insensitive](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html).

Right now your procedure has a query with this condition:

```
WHERE ScheduleID = ScheduleID AND LocationID = LocationID
```

Which evaluates as `true AND true` because comparing a column to itself is bound to be true (unless the column is NULL).

So with the `LIMIT 1`, the query returns the first row where both columns are not NULL.

Comment: That was it... I am in the process of porting over from SQL Server so I didn't even think twice about this.